# How should population sample characteristics be presented for a small sample size?

Tags: descriptive-statistics, small-sample, clinical-trials

I'm performing a clinical trial and have enrolled 16 patients, of which 3 had to be excluded. I suppose it would be relevant to present some characteristics of the included patients, e.g. age, weight, gender distributions.

Presenting gender is easy, but for age and weight: Does it make sense to present mean and standard deviation when n=13? Or should I present median and quartiles? Or mean and range?

Comment: It is difficult to give an advise now knowing more detailes about what you want to model and what is the purpose of your model. But linear regression could be one of the choices. Convert gender identifier to 0-1's and put a linear regression on all three covariates. On the other hand the sample is very small. I would definately use Bayesian inference instead of classical statistics for small samples.

Comment: Hi @Tomas! I just want to describe the enrolled patients. I'm not looking to model any behavior or find any correlation between the parameters. The actual trial that I'm performing is not related to age/weight/gender. (Did I understand you correctly?)

Comment: The for the age covariate you could just report an interval of ages, say [10; 55]. If you just want to describe the enrolled group of patients, then interval would suffice I think. Any point statistics (mean, median) is useless for such a small sample. Quartiles would not say anything usefull (or reliable) also. The range, in my subjective opinion, is sufficient.

Comment: @Tomas Thank you! Do you know of any discussion or textbook that states this? It would be useful to convince both myself and my coauthors.

Comment: This could be deduced from the general knowledge about how classical statistics works. Usually there are many asymptotics and approximation in those methods - this makes them unstable in case of small sample sizes. The info about these kinds of issues could be found in various papers, which are mostly highly technical (and "mathematical").
You should think first, how much information your characteristic would provide? In my subjective opinion it is more informative to have a range of values rather than a point estimate.

Comment: The range reflects the variation of your data, while point estimate gives no additional information. If you have a sample of 15 people and 13 people have age 55, while 2 are of age 10, then the mean is 47.8. This point estimate is not very usefull, because sample is small and mean value is sensitive to the outliers (2 people of age 10 in my case). The same reasoning goes in other cases of point estimates. 
So, at first you should ask yourself (and your collegue) what is the purpose of the quantity you want to calculate.

Answer (score 1):

For presentation purposes, in most cases, it's preferable to show frequencies inside specific brackets rather than means, medians etc. That's true even for small samples.

Now, these brackets depend more on your study rather that the quantiles. Take "age" for instance. In my field of work I usually use the age brackets: 18-24, 25-29 etc because these are the different segments of the customer database we have. Even if 18-24 customers are much fewer than 25-29 customers. In your case you may choose groupings such as children < 9 months old, 9-12 months if your study is a pediatric study or something different if it's on elderly people and so on. I believe it's more a judgement call rather than anything else.

Similarly for weight. If you want to assess under-weighted, normal and over-weighted patients then these should be your presentation brackets rather than some means, medians, quantiles etc

It's usually good to have some kind of an end goal in mind to guide you through your initial descriptive analysis but not fully dictate it or bias it if that makes sense.